# How to make sure an ajax call's result arrived before starting the next one while both are binded to the same onclick?

Tags: html, reactjs, ajax

I have 2 ajax calls, the second needs the first's result as input. My problem is that I want to call both of them at the same click. And however I tried I can't manage to get the first's result before the second starts.

If I create a second button and manually make the delay everything works. I tried to call a third function with sleep between the two functions but even that didn't work. Any idea would be very helpful, thank you! I bind the two functions two the button's onclick through a third function.

```
     sendSearchToDB = event => {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/user/GetUsers',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(this.state.searchExpression),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: (data) => {
                this.setState({peoples: data})                    
            }});
    }
```

The second ajax:

```
getBoolArray = event => {
    let string = this.props.email
    this.state.peoples.forEach(item => {
        string = string + "$" + item.id
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/user/PendingFriendRequest',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(string),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: (data) => {
                this.setState({boolArray: data})
        }});
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the second ajax call within the success of the first ajax call. In this way you will get the result of first one and pass it to the second one